# Windows: suppress warning when plugging in unformatted flash drive

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I'm working on a device that writes some information directly to a flash drive, without using any file system (it just writes blocks of data directly to the disk sectors). After the flash drive is filled, I need to plug it into any computer with windows and read data using my application.

Everything works great except for when I plug the flash drive in windows warns me that flash drive is invalid an offers me to format it. I want to get rid of this message for my flash drives on any computer that have installed my windows application.

My flash drive have signature bytes at the start so I can always make out whether it's my flash drive or just a regular flash drive.

My idea is that I should be able to write some sort of service or driver which will check all flash drives and will disallow OS to mount my drives. However I don't know whether its really possible and I can't find any documents mentioning this sort of functionality.

I'd appreciate any docs / links / functions names that can help me suppress unformatted disk warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a tiny real partition at the start and format it to keep windows happy.
Then just use the rest of the drive as you please

Comment: I'd still prefer something that hides the disk from the user altogether, but this looks like a possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to actually work -- at least, not on Windows 7.   I have 2 partitions, the first is formatted Fat32, the second is blank.  Windows still complains about the second with an apparently un-suppressable popup.

Comment: @Stabledog It does work for me. I made a classic MBR with two partition records. First one is fat32, the other one uses unknown partition type. Combined this two partitions occupy the entire disk.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well I found that I had to go into the Disk Management app and delete the drive letter that Windows had allocated for the 2nd partition.  Then it stopped complaining.  Maybe on yours, the drive letter never came into being in the first place?   I think that's the trigger for the popup -- Windows sees the partition, and if it can derive a drive letter, then it goes to look for a file system and complains if not found.   Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

Remove the drive letter assigned to the device:

1. Right-click the 'Computer' (or 'My Computer') icon on your desktop or in the Start Menu and select Manage. The 'Computer Management' window should appear.
2. From the list on the left, select 'Disk Management' (within the Storage sub-tree).
3. Right-click the encrypted partition/device and select Change Drive Letter and Paths.
   Click Remove.

If Windows prompts you to confirm the action, click OK.